# Converting date() to time() but date has a specific format

Tags: php, date, time

I just need your help really much. I have this date() format:

```
<?php
date("j. n. Y G:i:s");
?>
```

But later in the code i need to convert it into time() (using strtotime), but it fails. I don't know any function to do that. And here comes my question - do you know any function? Or do you atleast know how to convert it? I will be very thankful.

Comment: what do you mean as it fails? does it give you an error?

Comment: Well. I'm saving the value of this date() into MySQL. Then I take it out of MySQL and compare it with the actual date.

`if(time() >= strtotime($row->time)) { ... }`

And this gives me no errors because the strtotime($row->time) actually returns no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But later in the code i need to convert it into **time()** (using
>   strtotime),

Simply:

```
echo strtotime($yourTimeString);
```

Should give you timestamp in format of `time()` function.

Comment: `strtotime('G:i:s')` produces `FALSE`.  Did you mean `date()` instead?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't mention something really, really important.
I'm putting the result of my date() function into MySQL database and then compare it with the actual date.

Now I have:
`if(time() >= strtotime("j. n. Y G:i:s", $row->time)) { ... }`

But it says
**A non well formed numeric value encountered in...**

I'm really sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: This info should go in your original question, not in a comment.  It will enable others to give a meaningful answer without having to read everyone's answers and the comment threads first.

Comment: It should be `if(time() >= strtotime(date("G:i:s", strtotime($row->time))) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The `date()` function accepts a second argument, a UNIX timestamp, the same kind of timestamp that `strtotime()` produces.  In your example, you're not passing `date()` a timestamp, so it uses the value of the `time()` function.  No need to parse your timestamp back out from your formatted date string; you already have it.